# Pinned Metadata Termset sorting

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I have written a Powershell script to change the custom sort order of the Metadata Termset. This Termset is pinned Termset and the sorting is not affected in all the Member of Termset. How can i do this ?.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

$taxonomySession = Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site "http://sp/sites/dev"

$termStore = $taxonomySession.TermStores["Mananged Metadata"]
if($termStore -ne $null)

{
        $group = $termStore.Groups["System"]

```
    if($group -ne $null)

    {                         
        $termSet = $group.TermSets["Keywords"]
        $term1 = $termSet.Terms["#Jerry"]
        $term2 = $termSet.Terms["#Tom"]
        $customSortOrder = $term2.Id.ToString() +":"+$term1.Id.ToString()
        Write-Host($customSortOrder)
        $termSet.CustomSortOrder = $customSortOrder 
        $termStore.CommitAll();
    }
```

}

Comment: Yes the above Script only affects the Termsets "Keywords" but the pinned Termsets (MemberOf) will not get the Customorder automcatically.